# Is there a way to update a Database Project(or dacpac) from a live SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql-server, dacpac, azure-data-studio, schema-compare

So the scenario here is that I have done a bunch of work (i.e changing table names, rewriting and renaming SPs, synonyms etc) in a database within our live DEV SQL server. Now I want to move all my changes to our version control where this same database is stored as a Database Project Folder (i.e contains .sqlproj file as well as schema folders, etc). I so far am able to extract the Database from the DEV server as an external dacpac file and I am able to do a schema compare, setting the target to the database Project, however the button to apply the schema compare changes is greyed out as the target must be another existing database on a server.

I also have noted that the schema compare just builds a dacpac file for the Database Project first and then uses that for the Schema compare.

So is there anyway to update this old dacpac file or the whole Project folder given another dacpac file?

I am also doing all this via Azure Data Studio. Will appreciate any tips or advice :)

Comment: The Visual Studio compare does allow a source dacpac to be used to update a project. Given the ADS version is still in preview, perhaps it hasn't yet been implemented. If you don't already have VS installed, you could use the Community Edition for this purpose.